# switch statement reverting to default regardless of user input?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, default

What I want the program to do is ask for user input, take a number 1-7, and spit out the correct WriteLine statement. Everything compiles fine but I get the default WriteLine option no matter what number I enter. Where am I going wrong?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace week4discussion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            int userInput = Console.Read();

            switch (userInput) {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your selected course is IT 145");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your selected course is IT 200");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your selected course is IT 201");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your selected course is IT 270");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your selected course is IT 315");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your selected course is IT 328");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your selected course is IT 330");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number 1-7");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the docs about [Console.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_Read) or add a _Console.WriteLine(userInput);_ to see what is returning

Comment: I did that and found that the number being returned is somehow the value of whatever number I enter plus 48. For example, when I enter 1 in the user input, I get 49 returned to me, 2 is 50, and 3 is 51. I have no idea how it's adding 48 to any of that.

Comment: That's because Read return the [ASCII code](https://www.ascii-code.com/) of the key pressed not the numeric value stamped on the key. In any case using Read is a poor choice because it returns immediately after the first key is pressed. Now if you need to get 10 as input you get only the 1 and not the 0

Comment: @TophHughes I believe when you are debugging it and finding your number + 48 is because it is displaying the ASCII value for the number character (Ex: '1' is ASCII 49). Try the answer below with parsing the input for an integer or using the character values in your case statements. Ex: `case "1":, case "2":, case "3", ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this:

```
 int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Correct (if the input is a number) but please explain what is the error. Now if the user types "this is my number" your answer will crash the program

Comment: You need to parse the input from the user first to determine if it is a number or not. Here is a c# fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NcM8GD

Comment: @JakeSteffen Please edit your answer with tryparse.